# how to create multiple virtual NIC which each of them can take IP from DHCP when only single physical NIC is available

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, virtualization, network-adapter

There are several virtual machine tools that can create multiple NIC for their guest OS. thought almost all of them let the virtual NIC of the guest OS to connect the physical NIC, I haven't seen any tool to connect multiple virtual NICs to single physical NIC that each of them can take IP from the DHCP server and send packet with LAN IP. for some reason I don't want to make NAT to solve this problem.
   I need each NIC has their own IP address and communicate directly to the DHCP server. I also prefer not to use virtual machine to declare multiple NIC but if it is the only choice it is admitted subject to multiple NIC is declared in single guest OS. so for more clearance I itemize my constraints:

-needed operating systems: windows 
-multiple virtual NIC where each NIC take IP from DHCP server
-only one physical NIC is available
-each IP should be assigned to a virtual mac address and the choice of multiple IP per single mac address is not our goal. hence we need multiple virtual mac address when communicating to the DHCP server.

Comment: Hey, I use both VMware ESX and Hyper-V heavily and they all allow multiple VNIC's to connect to one Physical NIC on the Server/Machine. I've also used VMware Workstation and this also allows the same with individual IP's and Mac Addresses. Sorry if I've misunderstood what you are after but from reading it seems most Hypervisors would work for your purpose?

Comment: i am using hyper V at the moment, but it doesn't support multiple external VNIC to be connected to single physical NIC. i don't want each VNIC to take internal IP or private IP. i want it to masquerade a separate MAC address and take IP from external DHCP server. what vmware esxi version are you using ? If you feel you have done what I mean please initiate an answer and write the step by step progress for both VMWARE esxi and hyper V and get up vote.

Comment: Ah ok I think I better understand what your after now sorry I haven't ever gone down that path before. You would be better with this question on ServerFault rather than SuperUser IMO

Comment: You do realize that Windows and Linux are very different in that regard, right? As is, this question is too broad. That’s also why it wasn’t answered.

Comment: The operating system is limited to windows.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows XP, 2K, or Server Editions, use the Microsoft Loopback Adapter. This gives you a separate (virtual) devices, each with it's own MAC and IP stack. Although it's called a "loopback" adapter, it actually allows you to connect between --it's not limited to just creating closed loops.

Note: you can install the adapter on other Windows editions, the server editions allow you to route it as you require.