# Windows System 2019 configure nic teaming report "The parameter is incorrect."

Tags: windows, router, virtualization, network-adapter

## background:

I refer to the following article for configuration.
http://woshub.com/configure-nic-teaming-windows/

But I got "new-NetLbfoTeam : The parameter is incorrect."

output like this

```bash
new-NetLbfoTeam : The parameter is incorrect.
At line:1 char:1
+ new-NetLbfoTeam
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (MSFT_NetLbfoTeam:root/StandardCimv2/MSFT_NetLbfoTeam) [New-NetLbfoTeam],
   CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Windows System Error -2147024809,New-NetLbfoTeam
```

[gui report error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5rjV.png)

[powershell report error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYoUV.png)

## What is my problem

1. I want to know how to solve this error

Comment: You cannot create a team with a NIC if that NIC is already assigned to a virtual switch. If that's your case, remove the virtual switches, create the team, then create a team NIC on it.

Comment: If so, could you please look at [another related question](https://superuser.com/questions/1748983/windows-create-virtual-ethernet-adapter-base-a-single-physical-adapter-then-link).

Comment: Are you trying to aggregate NICs for combined bandwidth? If so, it doesn't work like this.

Comment: @harrymc [sure it does](https://todayamerican.medium.com/the-definitive-guide-on-getting-multi-gigabit-speeds-using-gigabit-network-adapters-in-windows-10-3d0568d9534b)